# Theano ImportError and process Warning when compiling function

Tags: theano

I am running Theano with Anaconda on Windows. Ihave pretty much followed the steps in the comments [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/otto-group-product-classification-challenge/forums/t/13973/a-few-tips-to-install-theano-on-windows-64-bits). I can import theano with no problems:

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T
x = T.vector('x')
W = T.matrix('W')
dot = T.dot(x, W)
```

This works fine. But when I do

```
f = theano.function(inputs=[x, W], outputs=dot)
```

I get warnings:

```
WARNING (theano.gof.compilelock): Overriding existing lock by dead process '4844' (I am process '3908')
WARNING:theano.gof.compilelock:Overriding existing lock by dead process '4844' (I am process '3908')
```

and a long error, which ends with:

```
ImportError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', CGemv{inplace}(AllocEmpty{dtype='float64'}.0, TensorConstant{1.0}, W.T, x, TensorConstant{0.0}), '\n', 'DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.', '[CGemv{inplace}(<TensorType(float64, vector)>, TensorConstant{1.0}, W.T, x, TensorConstant{0.0})]')
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: The warnings can be ignored (they occur because you have force-stopped a previous execution which held a lock to the Theano cache; the new process detects this and acquires the lock for itself). I recommend searching with the query *Theano "DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found."*. https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Theano+"DLL+load+failed%3A+The+specified+module+could+not+be+found."

Answer (score 1):

Theano on Windows need Theano development version and not last Theano version:

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install.html#bleeding-edge-install-instructions

So just update Theano and it should work.